# Lower bound for a probability expression

Tags: probability, random, upper-lower-bounds, gaussian

Let $z$ be the standard gaussian vector, $z\sim N(0,I_k)$. I was wondering if one can find a lower bound for the following expression
$$1-P\{\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}z\leq t\}$$

where $t\in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}z\sim N(0,\Sigma)$.

By using Slepian's inequality one can find an upper bound by simplifying the covariance matrix. I don't know how we can find a lower bound for the above aexpression.

Comment: Is the vector inequality taken component-wise?

Comment: Yes, it is component-wise.

Comment: Wild guesses: All components independent or all completely correlated.